# One ticket, two airlines, bags not checked to final destination

Tags: luggage, international-travel

Who is responsible for compensating me for my rebooked ticket to Istanbul? [image: attachment] My return ticket(see attachment) booked through Expedia UK on a single itinerary was on two different airlines. Aeromexico agent would not check my bag from Mexico through Amsterdam to my final destination...Istanbul, Turkey, on Turkish Airlines. He said they were not parter airlines. The flight was diverted and late arriving to Amsterdam and I had to pick up baggage to recheck on Turkish airlines (through passport control etc).Consequently, I missed my flight to Turkey and had to purchase an expensive ticket next day to get home. Expedia did not disclose on the ticket issues with two different airlines, but says Aeromexico is responsible. Aeromexico says they are not responsible to refund a flight on a different airline that it is Expedia UK's problem.

Comment: Some countries doesn't have clear 'sterile' transit option, USA being one. In that case you have to always recheck the baggage.

Comment: Did you miss the connection because of flight delay? Or delay in immigration and rechecking the bag?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It sounds like you had a terrible experience but what can we help you with?

Comment: The airlines won't take responsibility because they are not responsible. Each airline got you and the bags you checked in to where they were supposed to get you and they did that. They had no responsibility to manage your holiday after that and likely didn't even know about the the rest of your journey. The person responsible is either yourself or maybe the travel agency who booked it as their job is to basically make life easier for inexperienced travelers. Chalk it up to an expensive lesson, there really isn't anything else you can do.

Comment: @KeithLoughnane If the whole trip was effectively sold as a single ticket, then whoever issued that ticket is responsible for getting the passenger and their bags to their final destination timely. Now the issue is whether Expedia sold multiple tickets as if if were a single one without any notification, or if it was someone else.

Comment: Do you have the details of your e-ticket(s)? Can you edit your post with those details? This should contain ticket numbers, and who issued the ticket(s). The issuer can also be found from the prefix of the ticket number, if it's not clearly stated elsewhere. Please blank out any personal details, including a couple of digits in the middle of the ticket number(s).

Comment: Thank you for including the additional information. Could you share the 3 first digits of the ticket number? From you screenshot it looks like it's actually KLM who issued the ticket, but the ticket number prefix will confirm that.

Comment: Also, is there really a single ticket number? You masked quite a bit of text, aren't there multiple ticket numbers? How many travellers were there (there should be one ticket number per traveller if it was indeed a single airline booking).

Comment: There was only me traveling, one ticket number, first three digits #139